# Cookies not deleting all the time angular 7

Tags: cookies, angular7

I use ngx-cookie-service to store my token but when i click Disconnect  does not delete the cookies everytime. Sometimes its working, but sometimes it not.

sometime i need just to reload the page to make sure cookies are deleted,sometime it works fine but it not redirect me to login page  .
i tested it in localhost and in build same thing .
for the browser i use chrome

To set my token i use this :

```
 setAuth(value, expireTime): void {
this.cookieService.set('id_token', value, expireTime, '../');
```

}

I am using following code to delete a cookie:

```
clearCookies(){this.cookieService.deleteAll('../');}
```

and this my logout function:

```
  logOut() {
let path = location.pathname;
if (path.indexOf('/panier') > -1 || path.indexOf('/store') > -1) {
  this.setLogout({ value: true });
} else {
  this.disconnect().subscribe(res => {
    if (res.status == 'success') {
      this.setLogout({ value: false })
      this.clearCookies();
      this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    }
  })
}
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

can you try with Following

```
 logout() {
            this.cookieService.deleteAll('/', 'xyz.net');       
        }
```

here '/' is Path and xyz.net domain name , which you have specified while setting the Cookie
this code is working for me . it will remove all cookie with same domain i guess

Answer (score 16):

I was having the same problem in Angular8 (also in Angular 6 and 7 before). I found the answer in the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service

Apparently the cookieservice saves cookies by path. So as stated in the documentation, if you are not sure under which path you should delete: add '/'

I used the following method

```
logout(): void {
        this.cookieService.delete('TESTCOOKIE', '/');
    }
```

this works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
this.cookieService.deleteAll('/', domainName);
```

instead of

```
this.cookieService.deleteAll('../')
```

or

```
this.cookieService.deleteAll()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).